# Where in Chrome folder browser save hsts cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I need to find file, where chrome write HSTS cookies. What is the path?

I tried to find in C:\Users<your_username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ into file Cookies, but found nothing.

Where I can find file with HSTS Cookies?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think that I find - hsts cookies stored in Default folder in file - TransportSecurity